# Does QTP 10 supports automating Flash web-applications?

Tags: qtp

I am trying to automate a web-application that some of its features are Flash Based.
I am using the Object Spy in order to detect elements located inside the Flashed based feature but it identifies only the main feature as "WinObject:MacromediaFlashPlayerActiveX".
Meaning , it does not identify any elements located inside the Flash-Based feature.

Is there any option to click elements located inside the the Flash-Based feature, except for using x,y cordinates ?

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 2):

Plain Flash applications aren't supported by QTP, however Flex applications are supported by a module supplied by Adobe (search for QTP in [this link](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/2/install.html)).

Answer (score 0):

you need a license for Flex Plugin which is provided by Adobe for the Flex based web application. If you build your application using the steps defined by the Adobe team, than definitely this object recognize issue will be sorted. I suggest to gather the information on which technology the AUT is built and than go further on this.